# Не работает триггер MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Имеется 2 таблицы: **sale** и **car_in_stock**.

**sale**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
**car_in_stock**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создал триггер при добавлении новой записи в таблицу, триггер обновляет поле **sale.full_price_discount**.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При добавлении новой записи возникают ошибки

Если поле **sale.full_price_discount** пустое - то возникает ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если поле **sale.full_price_discount** равно числу - то возникает ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить ошибку?

Comment: Перепишите код/ошибки текстом, со скринами не удобно работать.
Первое что видно - не правильная логика в `UPDATE`, вы обновляете одну таблицу, а в `WHERE`обращаетесь к другой, там должен быть отдельный запрос для получения значения. Второе - Вы при добавление не пустое поле передаете(пустое - `null`), вы передаете пустую строку, ключевое слово - строка, а поле у Вас `float`

Comment: @asanisimov 
**Ошибка пустого значения**
There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database
Executing:
INSERT INTO `dealership`.`sale` (`date_sale`, `full_price_with_discount`, `staff_id_staff`, `customer_id_customer`, `car_in_stock_id_car`) VALUES ('2021-03-20 21:00:00', '0', '1', '1', '1632');

ERROR 1054: 1054: Unknown column 'car_in_stock.id_car' in 'where clause'
SQL Statement:
INSERT INTO `dealership`.`sale` (`date_sale`, `full_price_with_discount`, `staff_id_staff`, `customer_id_customer`, `car_in_stock_id_car`) VALUES ('2021-03-20 21:00:00', '0', '1', '1', '1632')

Comment: Минус за код картинками. Вставляйте код текстом.

Comment: @AK как вставлять код, чтобы оставалась табуляция?

Comment: Просто вставьте, я вам отформатирую в первый раз.

Comment: Четвёртая кнопка слева (с такими фигурными скобками) или хоткей Ctrl + K (предварительно нужно выделить текст, который хотите преобразовать в код)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE
    TRIGGER `update_full_price_after_insert` BEFORE INSERT 
    ON sale
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE price INT;
    SET @price = (SELECT full_price FROM car_in_stock WHERE car_in_stock.id_car = NEW.car_in_stock_id_car );
    SET NEW.full_price_with_discount = @price;    
    END
```

Comment: @AK спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Да, как-то так должно быть. А перед этой кнопкой находится кнопка "цитата" (то, что вы сначала сделали), она хороша когда вставляете текст ошибки.

Comment: А в вопросе? Тоже вставьте текст - поправлю оформление.

Comment: А зачем нужна промежуточная переменная-то? чтобы без BEGIN-END нельзя было обойтись?